# Old anime I saw about 15 years ago with transforming characters

Tags: story-identification, anime

Had to have been 15-ish years ago. The only episode I really remember well has the protagonist trapped, and the villain has the protagonist's love interest watching him. The villain keeps goading him into transforming and showing the love interest his "true form". The love interest is confused but tells him to do whatever he has to to survive. I believe the villain was some kind of spider demon and the protagonist was a werewolf or similar. I do remember it being rather gory. I've tried Googling “werewolf protagonist” and “spider demon kidnaps girl true form anime”, and many different combos in between. I even had a lot of my friends who are super into anime try to identify it, and everytime I meet a new person into anime I end up bringing it up at some point, but nobody remembers. Am I crazy?

Some more info, I do remember the romance being kinda cheesy, and as I said in the below comment, the art style was more serious like cowboy bebop. I said episode, but for all I know this could've been a movie.

Another edit, it seems like the setting was in a city like industrial revolution or just before industrial revolution London

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SF&F SE! You did pretty good giving us some information about what you saw (and thanks for Googling some of the obvious information beforehand!), but there is still more that would be useful. Did you see this on tv? What channel? What language was it in? Any other identifying characteristics for either the main character or love interest? _Inuyasha_ immediately springs to mind, what with a main character that fits some of those descriptions.

Comment: Definitely wasn't Inuyasha, I'm pretty sure it was either on toonami or adult swim. The art style was more like cowboy bebop if I'm remembering correctly. There was no "other" world, it was semi-modern and it seems like the people who could shape shift were discriminated against heavily

Comment: Shows run by toonami https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Toonami  None of them sound like what you are looking for.  Shows run by adult swim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Adult_Swim

Comment: I've actually already went through every show in the adult swim list and none of them sounded like it. All I know is I definitely watched it on tv and it was definitely late at night

Comment: Perhaps Wolf's Rain?

Comment: Hellsing Ultimate might fit as well

Comment: You know, Everytime I've ever tried doing research into this, wolf rain always seemed like the closest answer. If someone can find a clip of a protagonist transforming to get out of a web/net to escape a spider demon/catcher who has a female that the protagonist cares about held hostage, I'll accept that as an answer

Comment: @F.Sullivan In Wolf's Rain, the wolves only look human. They don't actually transform, you simply see through the illusions on occasion

Comment: @Machavity can they not turn off the illusion at will?

Comment: @F.Sullivan I did forget about [Darcia](http://wolfsrain.wikia.com/wiki/Darcia). He does change

Comment: Devilman, maybe?

Comment: @Machavity definitely didn't look like him, but the wolf and art style do look very familiar in this context

Comment: that maybe some literation of Devilman  or some works from Kawajira actually that was spider style villain in Cutey Honey but that more comedy that horror

Answer (score 3):

***[To the Abandoned Sacred Beasts](https://myanimelist.net/anime/39199/Katsute_Kami_Datta_Kemono-tachi_e)***. The MC is a werewolf. The main villain is a vampire that work with several monster beast including a woman who can transform into spider monster. They both abducted the MC's love interest to make him lost control of his ability and transform into his "true form" : a giant white fenrir. The setting somewhat like in industrial revolution since the technology isn't advanced and there is no full-automated riffle.
Edit:

> If someone can find a clip of a protagonist transforming to get out of a web/net to escape a spider demon/catcher who has a female that the protagonist cares about held hostage, I'll accept that as an answer

Apparently you asked for some clip so here you go

Answer (score 1):

Try *Basilisk*, it’s a Romeo and Juliet type story where it’s gory and the protgonist fights a spider monster and there's several characters with different powers. It aired in 2005 so that kinda fits.